# Is it possible to display the map with only the address?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to use GoogleMaps API v3.
Before, I was using version n°2 and I had just to put the address and the map was displayed.
Is it always possible with version n°3 ?
If yes, how ?
I always find scripts with latitude, longitude... but no script with address.
Thanks a lot and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mixed up Maps-Javascript-API and the Static-Maps-API(current Version is V2).

In the static-maps-API you may use an address as center-parameter.

In the Javascript-APIs you need a LatLng (no matter if V2 or V3). If you only have an adress, you must request the LatLng using a geocode-request.

Comment: To request the LatLng, does a script exist ? 
I don't want get it on a website but I would like to have LatLng with giving an address, is it possible ? If yes, where ?
Thanks again.

Comment: Yes: there's an example in the documentation. https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to look for something called geocode. It is a part of API documentation. something like below will help:

```
    var geocoder;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }

  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map, 
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

[Helpful Link](http://tech.cibul.net/geocode-with-google-maps-api-v3/)